# Sql 2008, invalid character parsing xml with characters with tilde

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008, html-encode

I'm parsing a xml text which contains characters like 'á é ñ'.

I'm getting a 'An invalid character was found in text content.' error, like this

```
declare @Xml varchar(100)

set @Xml =
'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root>á</Root>
'

declare @XmlId integer

execute dbo.sp_xml_preparedocument @XmlId output, @Xml

select * from openXml( @XmlId, '/', 2) with (
  Root varchar(10)
)
execute dbo.sp_xml_removedocument @XmlId
```

And I'm getting the following error:

```
The XML parse error 0xc00ce508 occurred on line number 3, near the XML text "<Root>".
Msg 6602, Level 16, State 2, Procedure sp_xml_preparedocument, Line 1
The error description is 'An invalid character was found in text content.'.
Msg 8179, Level 16, State 5, Line 13
Could not find prepared statement with handle 0.
Msg 6607, Level 16, State 3, Procedure sp_xml_removedocument, Line 1
sp_xml_removedocument: The value supplied for parameter number 1 is invalid.
```

Is there some way that sql can parse this xml? Or the problem is the encoding?

Is the only solution to encode those characters or is there a more elegant way to solve it?

Answer (score 5):

I got same error today that passing serialized object as xml to my store procedure. Eventually I found where the mistake is.

Change your code from:

```
declare @Xml varchar(100)
```

To:

```
declare @Xml nvarchar(100)
```

*Here is summary I found online, hopefully help you.*

An `nvarchar` column can store any Unicode data. A `varchar` column is restricted to an 8-bit codepage (non-Unicode character data). Using `nvarchar` rather than `varchar` can help you avoid doing encoding conversion every time you read from or write to database.

Comment: Print out your @Xml and you should see this

Answer (score -1):

The character á character is not a valid valid for utf-8 encoding. This is what any xml validator should tell you. The solution is to encode it properly.

If you are gettting the data from someone else, you should tell them they are doing it wrong. If you generate this data, you should fix this. Assuming you are stuck in the middle, it is possible to write a pre-processor for the file that "fixes" invalid XML before handing it of to your process that requires valid XML (vendors unwilling or unable to provide valid XML should be avoided whenever possible)

ADDED

You will be unsuccessful in a quest to convince TSQL to parse XML that won't validate.